# Semi-direct product and unitary group: need for subgroups to share only the identity.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

The Lie algebra $u(2)$, say, is the direct sum $u(1) \oplus su(2)$, where $u(1)$ has dimension one with generator in the fundamental which we may as well take to be $1\!\!1$. Yet the Lie group $U(2)$ is not isomorphic to the direct product of the Lie groups $U(1) \otimes SU(2)$ where the group elements in $U(1)$ are $e^{i t}1\!\!1$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, nor is this group a semi-direct product! The reason usually given is that although the elements of $U(1)$ commute with those of $SU(2)$ (or both are normal subgroups) both subgroups share more than the identity element. Indeed, they both share $-1\!\!1$. To see this, take $t = i\pi$ for $U(1)$ and $\exp(i \pi \hat{n}\cdot \sigma)$ where the Pauli matrices, $\sigma$, are (proportional to) the generators of $su(2)$.

My question is why this is a big deal - certainly in the construction of a direct product $G = G_{1} \otimes G_{2}$ one can decompose any element $(g_{1}, g_{2})$ into $(g_{1}, I_{2})(I_{1}, g_{2})$, a product of elements from the two subgroups. It is also clear that the subgroups $G_{1} = (g_{1}, I_{2})$ and $G_{2} = (I_{1}, g_{2})$ share only the identity, but I struggle to see why this convenience should necessarily be taken forward to the reverse case that one decomposes a group into a direct product.

In particular, for $U(2)$ the $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$ subgroups commute, any element can be decomposed into a product of elements in the two subgroups (even $(-1\!\!1, -1\!\!1) = (1\!\!1, -1\!\!1)(-1\!\!1, 1\!\!1)$) and the product of two elements $(g_{1}, g_{2})(g'_{1}, g'_{2}) = (g_{1}g'_{1}, g_{2}g'_{2})$ is the obvious product that direct product groups are endowed with. The only obstruction seems to be that they share two common elements and I would like to understand why this is a problem.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Why would the two commuting (or normal) subgroups sharing more than just the identity element be a problem. Or reversed, why does the definition of a direct or semi-direct product require that the two subgroups share only the identity.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Another way of asking the same question: Why could I not define the direct product (or the semi-direct product) without the requirement that the two subgroups only share the identity. What would go wrong if I were to do that?

Comment: Why should you want to redefine the term direct product in such a peculiar and confusing way?

Comment: See it this way: there is a definition of the direct / semi-direct product. They have (at least in Cornwell chap2 sec7) 3 requirements. I think it is a reasonable question to ask why one of these requirements (that the groups share only the identity) cannot be relaxed. It would be helpful if you were to explain which part of my definition is "peculiar and confusing" so that I may address it.

Comment: @lux You are probably looking for the notion of a pullback or a pushout. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @lux (Though I think the specific construction you want is somewhere in between the two.)

Comment: I don't think so: I just want to understand why, if one attempts to decompose $G = G_{1} \otimes G_{2}$ for subgroups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ then one requires that $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ share only the identity element (I'm happy with the other requirements that $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ commute and every element of $G$ can be written as a product of elements in $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$).

Comment: @lux It's easier in the Abelian case. There is a general construction called a "central product," which *may* be what you want. See exercise 7.9 in Isaacs algebra. (Central product lets you glue two groups along isomorphic subgroups of their centers.)

Comment: If you drop that requirement it is not longer going to be the product, though. For example, it will not have the desirable universal property that people call "product' all throughout mathematics. It will be something else -- depending ont he properties you want, that may be: pullback or pusout (in some category, say groups or abelian groups), or central product. Also ... if you insist that $G_1$ and $G_2$ still commute with eachother, then their intersection is in their center. So I think you want the "central product."

Comment: @lux Where does one start? Direct product has an established meaning, so using it for something else will certainly confuse. In your jargon two group may have two non-isomorphic direct products. Your direct products need not be categorical products in the category of groups etc. etc. etc. It sounds like you are aiming to solve a "problem" that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: The reference (Cornwell) in my above comment & the 3 requirements for the direct product of two groups is the familiar, standard definition. It is the established meaning in the context of group theory. A useful exercise when learning mathematics is to consider the consequences of relaxing a restriction (the fundamental theorem of algebra over $\mathbb{C}$; what happens if you restrict to $\mathbb{R}$, for example). In this case, I can't see why the restriction that the two sugbroups share only the identity is necessary. What undesirable effect would relaxing this have on the resulting group?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've answered my own question - thank you to the community for offering useful suggestions.

If one wishes to try to decompose $G$ into two subgroups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ and state that $G$ is isomorphic to the product group $G_{1} \otimes G_{2}$ with the usual product $(g_{1}, g_{2})(g'_{1}, g'_{2}) = (g_{1}g'_{1}, g_{2}g'_{2})$ then it must be the case that $G_{1} \cap G_{2} = 1\!\!1$ simply because every element of $G_{1} \otimes G_{2}$ can be written as $(g_{1}, g_{2}) = (g_{1}, 1\!\!1)(1\!\!1, g_{2})$.

Since $U(2)$ does not satisfy this requirement it cannot possibly be isomorphic to $U(1) \otimes SU(2)$ nor $U(1) \ltimes SU(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ and $V$ be groups, and $Z(\_)$ denotes the center. The following is exercise $7.9$ in Isaac's algebra.

Let $M \subset Z(U)$ and $N \subset Z(V)$ and assume $M \cong N$. Then there is a group $G$ with normal subgroups $K$ and $L$ so that $K \cong U$ and $L \cong V$ and $KL = G$ and $[K,L] = 1$ (they commute) and $K \cap L = M$ (after identifying $K$ with $U$).

This is called the central product of $U$ and $V$ identifying $M$ and $N$.

Note that if you have two subgroup $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $G$, and you insist that they commute, then $G_1 \cap G_2$ is in the center of both of them.

See here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_product

In particular, on that page an "internal central product" is described. It appears to be what you want.

(I don't know if this answers your question at all. But it would be an unreadable comment.)

Also, if you want to know why the "product" is so special, see this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)